# How to write an csv file from S3 to DynamoDB line by line in Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I have csv file in an S3 bucket having the first row as header and rest of the rows as values. For example `data.csv` :

```
id | name | age | height
12 | abc  | 23  |  5.7
13 | xyz  | 25  |  5.3
```

I want to write the csv lines in DynamoDB table one by one. In order to do that, I want to store each row as an object (`StatusObject`) in java. Something like for each row, `StatusObject.setId(data[id])`, `StatusObject.setName(data[name])` and then write this object in DynamoDB.

I have a ddbMapper, that writes the object in DynamoDB table

```
ddbMapper.load(StatusObject.class, id);
```

This is how I retrieve the S3Object:

```
S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(s3bucket, s3Key));
S3ObjectInputStream s3ObjectInputStream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
```

Can someone help me with the following conversion?

`s3ObjectInputStream -> StatusObject` (the `data.csv` will have unnecessary columns which I want to avoid and only store ones to match the `StatusObject`

Thanks.

Comment: As discussed in my response - i have shown you an example of using AWS SDK for Java V2 to read data from an S3 bucket and store it in an Amazon DynamoDB table. Included in my response is to show you how to use the DynamoDB Enhanced Client instead of using V1 ddbMapper. V1 is not recommended to use anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar example in AWS Code Example Github repo. However, instead of reading a CSV file, it reads an Excel spreadsheet that is located in the S3 bucket and places the data into an Amazon DynamoDB table.

This example uses the Amazon [DynamoDB Enhanced Client Java API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/dynamodb-enhanced-client.html) (which is AWS SDK for Java V2). The **ddbMapper** is Java V1 which is [not recommended anymore](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples#aws-sdk-code-examples). You should consider moving away from ddbMapper to the Enhanced Client.

This example reads the data in the speadsheet:

[image]

and places the data into a DynamoDB table:

[image]

This example will point you in the right direction in terms of reading data from an S3 bucket and placing the data into an Amazon DynamoDB table using the AWS Java API.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/Creating_etl_workflow